# Feedback for Study Plan (Kali Linux & Penetration Testing)

Tags: penetration-test

I started to study pentesting for two months with the book named Penetration Testing - A Hands on Introduction to Hacking by Georgia Weidmann, and now I am really hungry to learn more :) . I think I found the right area to study for years (IT&Network&System Security). When finished my book I think that I must have a plan for my learning process to go deeper and to be master. I made a plan in which there are books, video tuts and certifications, and now I need some feedback about it (masters and profs can help me to improve it but any feedback from anyone are welcome).

And here my plan:

1. Information Gathering

   - Kali Linux Network Scanning Book (Book)
   - INE- Wireshark Advanced Technologies (Video Tut)
2. Threat Modelling

   - Kali Linux Cook Book(Book)
3. Vulnerability Analysis

   - Gray Hat Hacking - The Ethical Hacker's Handbook(Book)
   - Kali- Assuring Security by Penetration Test(Book)
4. Exploitation

   - Gray Hat Hacking - The Ethical Hacker's Handbook(Book)
   - Udemy - Certified Metasploit Framework Professional (Video Tut)
   - Kali Linux - Social Engineering(Book)
   - Web Penetration Testing with Kali(Book)
   - Udemy - Website Hacking in Practice(Book)
5. Post-exploitation

   - Gray Hat Hacking - The Ethical Hacker's Handbook(Book)
   - Mastering Kali Linux for Advanced Pen testing(Book)
   - Cybrary - Pen Test and Ethical Hack (Video Tut)
   - Kali Linux CTF Blueprints(Book)
   - Infiniteskills - Reverse Engineering and Exploit Development (Video Tut)
6. Mobile Hacking

   - Penetration Testing -Georgia Weidmann Chapter 20(Book)
7. Study through learning process:

   - Programming

     - Black Hat Python - Python Programming for Hackers and Pentesters(Book)
     - Penetration Testing with Bash Shell(Book)
   - Tactics and Techniques

     - Ninja Hacking - Unconventional Pen Test Tactics and Techniques(Book)

Prerequisites(also my b.g.):

- Linux & Microsoft Operating Systems Knowledge
- Networking (Reference models-OSI & TCP/IP, Protocols, Subnetting ex.)
- Programming (Functional and OOP knowledge; PHP, C/C++, Java)
- And, labour and patience :)

If one wants to work as pentester or IT/System Administrator, you should have some certifications, I think (especially in this area). Thus, there is a list for certifications:

- CISSP (Certified Information Systems Security Professional):

  - Official Link: https://www.isc2.org/cissp/
  - Study Sources:

    - Official (ISC)² Guide to the CISSP CBK Textbook
    - All-in-One CISSP Certification by Shon Harris
- OSCP (Offensive Security Certified Profesional):

  - Official Link: https://www.offensive-security.com/
  - Study Sources:

    - PWK by Offensive Security
- CEH (Certified Ethical Hacking)

  - Official Link:
  - Study Sources:

    - EC-Council Online Training
    - Ethical Hacking & Countermeasures (All of them)

And, there are resources for free times:

- The Tech Active Series - The Hacker's Manual 2015
- Kevin Mitnick's books
- Mikko Hypponen - Security Presentations (TED Talks)

Comment: Looks like you've given this some thought. Unfortunately, this is still a "recommendation question", and as such, off-topic.

Comment: @S.L.Barth Agreed. This is a great question that can generate some good discussion, unfortunately it's too open-ended for a Q&A site, as stated in http://security.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: Its a shame that this is off topic. As its a fairly decent reading list that people could stumble across, which could also help a lot of people in a similar situation...

Comment: @AaronDobbing There are a few options. We used to have Community Wiki. Or mods can lock the question but keep it as a canonical resource - they did a similar thing on Stack Overflow with the [The Definitive C Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). These options are not without controversy, but they are options.

Comment: Although I know it is open-ended question, I did not find any portal that I can ask for help on the web so far. I asked this question because there are a lot of sources about this topic, and there should be some filtering to eliminate, thx for answers anyway

Comment: @MikeOunsworth Well, the OP now has 20 points, so they can participate in chat. That might be a place to discuss it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks good to me but I can recommend you also to learn at least one or two programming languages (Definetely Python, JavaScript and maybe C/C++ at least you sholud know basic knowledge).

You can also download vulnerable application like DVWS http://www.dvwa.co.uk and test in your local environment. You can also download metasploitable linux vulnerable operating system.

I recommend also to download BurpSuite and learn as much as you can about HTTP protocol.

Obviously if you have some spare money you can go for practical certificates like OSCP or at least subscription to SecurityTube.

You can add to the list also some books about cryptography (I recommend B.Schneier books).

I suggest also to use this forum because you can learn a lot from here.

Comment: thanks for your response. I studied C++ and Java before, and I have good knowledge about programming basics&OOP. there is python book in my list (at the end) named black hat python prog. I want to learn python as well as ruby after gaining good knowledge about pen-test. I'll keep your advice.